# Цикл по столбцам таблицы (%rowtype)

Tags: oracle, plsql

У меня type на запись таблицы.

```
declare
  SUBTYPE tDvijRow is TDVIJ%rowtype;
  df tDvijField;
begin
  df.count      := :vcount;
  df.price := :vprice;
 ....
```

Я хочу составить динамический запрос из этого типа по заданным переменным, но мне не хотелось бы вручную перечислять все поля таблицы, т.к. их много и хотелось бы что-то универсальное. 
Хотелось бы чтобы все выглядело как-то так:

```
  declare
    vSql varchar2(2000) := 'select ';
  begin  
    FOR i IN 1 .. df.Count()
    LOOP
      vSql := vSql || df [i].Value || ',';
    end loop;
    vSql := ' from dual';
  end;
```

Возможно ли такое?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен с помощью таблицы user_tab_columns:

```
tSql varchar2 (5000);
df tDvijField;
  function getTestRow return tSql IS
    vSql tSql;
    vVal tSql;
  begin
    for x in (select column_name, data_type
                from user_tab_columns
               where table_name = 'TDVIJ')
    loop
      if vSql is not null
      then
        vSql := vSql || ',';
      end if;                
        execute immediate 'begin :1 :=  df.'|| x.column_name||'; end;'
          using out vVal;           
        vSql := vSql || vVal || ' as ' || x.column_name;    
     end loop;
    vSql := 'select ' || vSql || ' from dual';
    return vSql;
  end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Просто передать переменную типа %rowtype в динамический sql не получится, так как динамический sql поддерживает только переменные sql типа, тогда как %rowtype это pl/sql тип.

Если Вы подробнее опишите для чего вообще Вам это нужно и что потом Вы собирались делать с результатами такого селекта, возможно можно будет придумать какой-то более подходящий вариант решения проблемы.

А так, можно попробовать сделать что-то вроде этого (текст анонимного pl/sql блока можно генерировать динамически):

```
create table MyTable
(
  val1 number,
  val2 varchar2(200),
  val3 date
)
/
insert into MyTable values (1, 'a', sysdate)
/

create or replace package MyPackage
as
  myTableRow MyTable%ROWTYPE;
end;
/

declare 
  l1 number;
  l2 varchar2(200);
  l3 date;
begin
  select * into MyPackage.myTableRow from Mytable where rownum <2;  

  execute immediate '
  declare 
    l1 number;
    l2 varchar2(200);
    l3 date;
  begin
    select MyPackage.myTableRow.val1, MyPackage.myTableRow.val2, MyPackage.myTableRow.val3 
    into l1, l2, l3 
    from dual;

    dbms_output.put_line(l1);
    dbms_output.put_line(l2);
    dbms_output.put_line(l3);
  end;';
end;
/
```